# trying to attach ss2008 r2 dev editn adventureworks.mdf without ldf getting 'file may be incorrect' message

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas

I am trying to use the technique suggested in the blog entry below (exhibit 2) to attach adventureworks.mdf without the ldf (many complain about microsoft not downloading ldf with the mdf - does anyone know where to download the mdf and ldf together??) and after the query runs for ten seconds (indicating I got the file path to the mdf right)  I get the following error message:

exhibit 1: error message

> File activation failure. The physical file name "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2008R2_Log.ldf" may be incorrect.
>   New log file 'C:\Users\Gary\Downloads\AdventureWorks_log.LDF' was created.

exhibit 2: blog entry

http://blog-rat.blogspot.com/2009/04/how-to-attach-mdf-without-ldf-into-sql_13.html

exhibit 3: code

```
USE master
GO
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks 
ON PRIMARY (FILENAME = 
N'C:\Users\Gary\Downloads\AdventureWorks2008R2_Data.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG 
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a warning and has nothing to do with AdventureWorks per se, just with attaching an mdf without a log. Didn't you find that the database was created and available for use, in spite of the message?

As for the download it's meant to be a single mdf file for simplicity. Since it's just as easy to create a new log as it would be to attach an empty log file.

Comment: i thought of that... i dont see the database in ssms.